# PHP - How to edit a key of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array that i need to edit the array :

```
    Array
(
    [E:\EasyPHP-cmsServer-14.1VC9\data\cms\sites\user_1\012014.user_1.txt] => TotalVisits 6788
    [E:\EasyPHP-cmsServer-14.1VC9\data\cms\sites\user_1\022014.user_1.txt] => TotalVisits 11141
    [E:\EasyPHP-cmsServer-14.1VC9\data\cms\sites\user_1\032014.user_1.txt] => TotalVisits 6143
    [E:\EasyPHP-cmsServer-14.1VC9\data\cms\sites\user_1\042014.user_1.txt] => TotalVisits 936
    [E:\EasyPHP-cmsServer-14.1VC9\data\cms\sites\user_1\052014.user_1.txt] => TotalVisits 936
    [E:\EasyPHP-cmsServer-14.1VC9\data\cms\sites\user_2\012014.user_2.txt] => TotalVisits 9
    [E:\EasyPHP-cmsServer-14.1VC9\data\cms\sites\user_2\022014.user_2.txt] => TotalVisits 25
    [E:\EasyPHP-cmsServer-14.1VC9\data\cms\sites\user_2\032014.user_2.txt] => TotalVisits 37
    [E:\EasyPHP-cmsServer-14.1VC9\data\cms\sites\user_2\042014.user_2.txt] => TotalVisits 17
    [E:\EasyPHP-cmsServer-14.1VC9\data\cms\sites\user_2\052014.user_2.txt] => TotalVisits 16
)
```

And I want to be like this :

```
Array
(
    [012014_user_1] => TotalVisits 6788
    [022014_user_1] => TotalVisits 11141
    [032014_user_1] => TotalVisits 6143
    [042014_user_1] => TotalVisits 936
    [052014_user_1] => TotalVisits 936
    [012014_user_2] => TotalVisits 9
    [022014_user_2] => TotalVisits 25
    [032014_user_2] => TotalVisits 37
    [042014_user_2] => TotalVisits 17
    [052014_user_2] => TotalVisits 16
)
```

Here's what I've tried :

```
foreach($myarray as $key => $value){
                        $exp_key = explode('\\', $key);
                        $exp_key_name = explode('.', $exp_key[6]);

                     $key = $exp_key_name[0]."_".$exp_key_name[1];

                    }
```

Any idea where's the error in my code? Thanks

Comment: You can't *edit* the key, but what you can do is make a new array.  `$newArray = array()`, then in your current `foreach`: `$newArray[$key] = $value`.

Comment: You can also use `basename` to get your original array in the desired format to begin with, instead of using the whole file path. Or hey, use a database for this instead of text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well simple solution is:

```
$array[$newkey] = $array[$oldkey];
unset($array[$oldkey]);
```

In your case you would loop through:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
   $newKey = end(explode("\\", $key)); //need latest php for this otherwise split end and explode

   $newArray[$newKey] = $value;
}
```